# jQuery function inside a function, works, but returns undefined

Tags: jquery, function, return, undefined

I'm trying to find the last child element of a jQuery element that I have selected via a jQuery function that I've written. if I place debugger inside the function and run it, I can track the value of 'current' and it's doing what I want - it bubbles down to the last child as I would hope, but it's not returning this at the spot where I call it (it returns undefined).

Code looks like:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.findBattleElement = function () {

        var current = this;

        var findLast = function () {
            if ( current.children().length > 0 ) {
                if ( current.children().last().is('br, p, span, td, ul, ol, li, tr, table, a, img, video, div, section, article, footer, header') ) {
                    current = current.children().last();
                    findLast();
                } else {
                    current.children().last().remove();
                    findLast();
                }
            } else {
                return current;
            }
        }

        findLast()
    };
} ( jQuery ) );
```

I did try removing the function inside the function, and got it to try recursively call itself, so instead of using
`findlast()`  in the first if/else, I used `current.findBattleElement()`, but then it just gave an error that the function itself was undefined.

I know the whole thing is a bit amatuerish (sorry about the indenting, it looks fine in my doc, but doesn't carry over to stackOverflow so well!), but I'm trying to learn. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To paste indented code in SO, make sure it only uses spaces, not tabs. Paste it in, then use the `{}` tool in the SO editor toolbar to mark it as code.

Comment: thanks! I will definitely indent better next time.
Can you specify though, which `findlast()` needs the 'return'? I would assume you mean the last one, that initially calls the function, but if I do that it now loses the value of 'current' by the time it gets to the last else.
It may be a flaw in my logic somewhere, but I'm sure debugger was returning a value here before! (I have been working on this for about 18 hours solid now so things are getting fuzzy!)

Comment: 12 hours later and I finally found it - I needed another `return current;` at the very end of the findLast function.

Comment: If you want to ask a question about a specific answer, you should put it in the comments below the answer, not the comments below the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
return findLast();
```

to return the value from the recursive function.